# Xcode7.3.1-Why the image can not be found and ended with exit code:255

Tags: c++, xcode

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;



int main()
{
char filename[] = "IMG_0851";
Mat image; //create an image matrix
```

I want to analysis the image in grayscale

```
image = cvLoadImage(filename,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); //load image in grayscale directly
if (image.empty())
{

    cout << "Image could not be found" << endl;
    return -1;
}

imshow("Image in RGB", image);


cvWaitKey(0); //wait for a keystroke in the window

return 0;
}
```

Build succeeded, however, the image cannot be found & program ended exit code: 255.

Comment: And the files *actual* name is just `IMG_0851`? No filename suffix (extension)? And it is in the process current working directory?

Comment: 255 is -1 cast to an unsigned byte. Some operating systems only allow one byte for exit codes.

Comment: You might need to provide more information for solving your issue, such as **how are you running the program ?**, what would be the **current working directory**, what is the **exact name of the image** when using `ls`

Comment: As for your return code, like told by @immibis not all systems support negative values. In fact POSIX systems (like macOS, formerly OSX) only allow a non-negative value in the range 0 to 255. That is because the exit code is part of a larger field in the parent process which only have 8 bits for the return status, and it's there considered an unsigned value.

Comment: the posted code is `C++`, not `C`  Strongly suggest replacing the `c` tag with the `c++`, so your question will be seen by those that are supporting `C++`.